# Node.js Execute after Line-by-Line Readline Finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, readline

This likely would happen to other async functions, but I'm using `readline` as an example, as that's the issue I encountered.

I've just started using JS and is currently trying to collect input from a file via stdin(`<`). An example would be the code below:

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', foo);

function foo(line) {
    // Code to be iterated by line
}

function summary() {
    // Code to be executed after rl finishes
}
```

So the question is, where do I put `summary` function? Does `rl.on` take another callback that is executed after it finishes?

**Clarification:** `foo` is called each time when `rl` reads a line and `summary` is called only once, which is after `rl` finishes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for [close event](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close):

```
rl.on('close', summary);
```

Comment: That won't work as in that case `summary` is called when each line is being read. In my case, I want `summary` called only once, and that is after `rl` finishes execution.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Yes that's what I've been looking for. Greatest thanks!